# Instruction to import OSM file using PostGIS in windows

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, windows-7, osmosis

I want to import OSM data into a PostGIS database running under windows. After a web search I learned that I should use osmosis. But most of the explanations are for Linux. But I have to use windows. Is there a detailed description how to do that with Windows?

Comment: "Osmosis quick install" in the OSM wiki at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Quick_Install_%28Windows%29 should be a starting point.

Comment: Also check https://www.geofabrik.de/ for some premade shapefiles based on OSM datasets that are ready for consumption.

Answer (score 5):

Osmosis is the swiss-knife for OSM data and therefore a great piece of software to handle OSM data. I'd recommend to follow the steps below to succesfully import OSM data into a PostGIS database in a windows environment:

- First of all you need to [download](http://postgis.net/windows_downloads/) and [install](http://postgis.net/install/) PostgreSQL with a PostGIS extension and download the [latest stable version of osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Latest_stable_version).
- Then you need to create the hstore extension using pgAdmin to store osm-tags in PostGIS: `CREATE EXTENSION hstore;`
- Create a database-schema for OSM data: Copy the code from `YourPathToOsmosis\script\pgsnapshot_schema_0.6.sql` into pgAdmin and execute it. Do the same with `YourPathToOsmosis\script\pgsnapshot_schema_0.6_linestring.sql` to enable linestrings (there are [other database schemas](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Databases_and_data_access_APIs#Database_Schemas) which might suite your needs. I prefer pgsnapshot because every single tag is imported. If you primarily want to render OSM data you'd better use the osm2pgsql schema).
- For better performance add indices: Again, execute `CREATE INDEX idx_nodes_tags ON nodes USING GIN(tags);` and `CREATE INDEX idx_ways_tags ON ways USING GIN(tags);` and `CREATE INDEX idx_relations_tags ON relations USING GIN(tags);` within pgAdmin.
- Now your database is ready to be filled with OSM data. Download your required OSM extract (e.g. [from the Geofabrik download server](http://download.geofabrik.de/)) and use osmosis within the commande line to import a *.pbf-file: `"YourPathToOsmosis\bin\osmosis" --read-pbf file="C:\YourPathToOSMFile\osm_file.osm.pbf" --write-pgsql host="localhost" database="yourDBname" user="postgres" password="yourPW"`

Answer (score 2):

Apart from osmosis, you can use [osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) to populate a Postgis database.

For links to Windows builds, see https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/17 and https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/472

The advantage of osm2pgsql is that you will get GIS-ready tables with the same content as used by the rendering toolchain.